# do_shortcode() doesn't do shortcodes ;)

Tags: theme-development, shortcode

Imagine this basic shortcode in your functions.php file:

```
function div_shortcode( $atts ) {
   return '<div class="div"></div>';
}

add_shortcode('div', 'div_shortcode');
```

So every  `[div]` in Wordpress editor gives `<div class="div"></div>`.

Everything looks and works fine, right?

Now here comes the trouble.

I need to use my shortcode in PHP file (not putting it via WP Text Editor).

Luckily there's a function for that:

```
<?php do_shortcode('[div]'); ?>
```

But, wait, it shows... nothing?

```
<?php do_shortcode('[gallery]'); ?>
```

Even this one doesn't work.

Why is that happening? Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shortcode functions just return a value, you need to echo or assign it to something.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[div]'); ?>
```

Comment: Christ, I've tried it before and nothing. But today it works. Stupid typos! Thank you so much! :)